# SCNSceneSource init is giving Ambiguous use of 'init(URL:options:)' error

Tags: swift, scenekit

This init is giving me an error:

> Ambiguous use of 'init(URL:options:)'

```
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL: url, options: [SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay])!
```

Please help me understand what the issue is, and how I might go about fixing it. Thanks so much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used uppercase letters in the `URL` parameter instead of lowercase. Replace

```
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL: url, options: [SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay])!
```

with

```
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: url, options: [SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay])!
```

Comment: Thanks- just caught that! Still getting the error though :(